# I am creating a database for a library project that has to give an error when inserted book is unreturned

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I've been tasked to build a sample library database for a school project. So far, mostly everything has been done, except, I need to create a trigger that fires when a librarian tries to check out a book that has not been returned yet by the previous lender.
This is the code for the table called `LenderRecord` that should condition the aforementioned inserts.

```
CREATE TABLE LenderRecord
(
RecordID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
MediaID INT,
LenderID INT,
DateTaken DATE NOT NULL,
DateReturned DATE, --YYYY-MM-DD FORMAT!
Reservation NVARCHAR(20),
FineAmtDue MONEY DEFAULT '0',
FineAmtPaid MONEY DEFAULT '0'
);
```

The code for the trigger: Please bear in mind that I am new to SQL...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_BookNotReturned  --This trigger fires when a mediaid is being inserted that has 
not bee returned by the previous lender.
ON LenderRecord
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS( SELECT MediaID FROM inserted WHERE DateReturned = '1900-01-01' )
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('This book has not been returned yet', 16, 1)
    END
END
GO
```

However, when I execute this trigger and insert data into the table, it only captures the inserts that have a `DateReturned` that is not '1900-01-01'.

Please could someone give me a better approach?
Thanks

Comment: can you provide an example of a record you're inserting that you expect to hit the trigger that isn't?

Comment: Don't use dummy dates like `'1900-01-01'` - leave the value `NULL`  and check by `WHERE DateReturned IS NULL`.

Comment: I don't think that your trigger does what you need it to do (unless I'm misunderstanding the requirements). When you `Select MediaId from inserted...`, the `inserted` table only contains the newly added/updated record. It doesn't contain all of the LenderRecords for that mediaId.

Comment: EXECUTE sp_LenderRecord_InsertUpdateDeleteSelect '72', '26', '2020-02-16', '', '', '', '', 'Insert'
EXECUTE sp_LenderRecord_InsertUpdateDeleteSelect '72', '29', '2020-02-22', '', '', '', '', 'Insert'

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to use the `INSERTED.MediaID` to find a `LenderRecord` where both conditions apply:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT MediaID FROM LenderRecord WHERE MediaID = INSERTED.MediaID AND DateReturned = '1900-01-01' )
```

However this will only work on `INSERT` so your trigger should only fire on `INSERT`, not on `UPDATE`.
If you fire your trigger on `UPDATE`, you'd never be able to set the `DateReturned` because your trigger would prevent it.

Also consider leaving `DateReturned` NULL until you have a valid date and filter for `DateReturned IS NULL` in your query.

Comment: I get this error when attempting this method: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trig_BookNotReturned, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 1372]
The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.MediaID" could not be bound.